# How to use the onScroll and onScrolling event in zk

Tags: java, events, zk

In my system, i want to add event listener to the component,like this:

```
itemCustGrid.addEventListener(Events.ON_SCROLLING, new EventListener<ScrollEvent>() {...});
```

then i check the zk, the grid component cannot support the onScrolling event or onScroll event.

```
Class HtmlBasedComponent:
 * <p>Events:<br/>
 *  onClick, onDoubleClick, onRightClick, onDrop,
 *  onMouseOver, onMouseOut, onOK, onCacnel, onCtrlKey and onSwipe.<br/>
```

so i register the event in my own component as follow:

addClientEvent(BaseGrid.class, Events.ON_SCROLLING, CE_IMPORTANT);
    addClientEvent(BaseGrid.class, Events.ON_SCROLL, CE_IMPORTANT);

but still can not work. it should how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll events can be listened to on the client side in JavaScript like this:

```
<listbox xmlns:w="client" w:onScroll='console.log("scroll")' />
```

You can apply a client side listener as shown in the zul, or by[`Component.setWidgetListener()`](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/8.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Component.html#setWidgetListener(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) in Java code.

In that client listener, you can then [send a custom event to the server side](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Communication/AU_Requests/Client-side_Firing#Fire_Event_to_Widget):

```
<listbox rows="2" xmlns:w="client" 
        w:onScroll='zAu.send(new zk.Event(this, "onClientScroll", {data: "I scrolled!"}, {toServer:true}));'
        onClientScroll='System.out.println(event.getData())'>
```

This will output `{"data":"I scrolled!"}` on the server side. Pay attention, though: The scroll event is thrown very often. You might want to delay the event sending a bit to limit traffic.

Comment: Thanks malte firstly, one more question, it means I needn't register the onScroll event or onScrolling event in the system?

Comment: No, not with this approach. On the client side, the onScroll event is already receivable out-of-the-box. And if you use `zAu.send()` with a custom event, you can just add a server side listener in Java with `Component.addEventListener()`. That's all you have to do: rethrow onScroll as custom event, and add a listener for that one.

Comment: yeah, I mean if I could use the way of Component.setWidgetListener() in java code directly? anything i should do?

Comment: I tested on [link](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/24ahj3i/100-Listen-Grid-scrolling). it is ok! but in my system. the same way cannot take effect！

Comment: That is strange. I copied your fiddle to my project and it works.

Comment: I think it doesn't support the onScroll event in my project, let me try more way about it. much thanks Malte

Comment: Good luck with that issue. I forgot to ask which zk version your are using. That might be of relevance. You can try to choose another version on zkfiddle (there is a dropdown on top).

Comment: Hi Malte, I am very happy to tell you that my problem have resolved, I have create a new component then add the zscript by this.fire("onScroll", {"data":"scroll!"},{toServer:true}). much thanks your advice!

Comment: Hello this is a very good and helpful question and answer too. I was stack a lot with this listbox and scroll incapability. May I ask is there any good reference on how to use zk events from client side as well with creating components that wrap up javascript staff like jquery  like tutorial or book (not from potix because it has lot of noise on their forums and sites ) ?

Comment: @hephestos Hi, glad it helped you! As for the tutorial: In our project, we cobbled together the information from the [reference documentation ](https://www.zkoss.org/documentation#References). Maybe you could ask a separate question on this to get more people to see it. I could also share a small example of how handle the client side of our custom components.